# Why the results of FindDistribution and DistributionFitTest are not consistent?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

```
data = {0.180723, 0.181208, 0.182213, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.1875, 0.1875,
0.1875, 0.1875, 0.190476, 0.191041, 0.19174, 0.192308, 0.192513
0.193038, 0.194118, 0.194858, 0.195172, 0.196141, 0.196507, 0.196911,
0.19717, 0.199725, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2,
0.204804, 0.204887, 0.206148, 0.207435, 0.208861, 0.211034, 0.213389,
0.214286, 0.214286, 0.214286, 0.215247, 0.218447, 0.22028, 0.221334,
0.221519, 0.222222, 0.224227, 0.224359, 0.225352, 0.226485, 0.230769,
0.230769, 0.230769, 0.230769, 0.230769, 0.230769, 0.231561, 0.23622,
0.239075, 0.24, 0.24, 0.241667, 0.241758, 0.246269, 0.247842, 0.25,
0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.254902,
0.26087, 0.26087, 0.264706, 0.269461, 0.272727, 0.273684, 0.277778,
0.287576, 0.28934, 0.295775, 0.298013, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.304124,
0.305085, 0.310345, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333,
0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.333333, 0.357143,
0.36, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.375, 0.387097, 0.4, 0.409091,
0.409091, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6}

dataDist = FindDistribution[data,3,
   {"CramerVonMises","PearsonChiSquare"},"RandomSeed"->23544325]
```

> {{GammaDistribution[7.34584,0.0353382],{0.896823,0.943734}},
>        {LogNormalDistribution[-1.41827,0.377612],{0.547505,0.252689}},
>        {WeibullDistribution[1.81133,0.194603,0.086273],{0.657403,0.786422}}}

```
Hdata=DistributionFitTest[data,GammaDistribution[7.34584,0.0353382],"HypothesisTestData"]
```

> ```
>   Statistic   P-Value
> Anderson-Darling    6.04043 0.000934535
> Cramér-von Mises    0.923269    0.00372792
> Pearson \[Chi]^2    77.2131 3.67716*10^-11
> ```

Based on the `FindDistribution` results the Gamma distribution seems to fit better these data.However, the `DistributionFitTest` did not confirm this conclusion. Why ? Where I am going the wrong way ?

Addendum:

The `FindDistribution` function  does not handle these data set either:

```
data1={1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.,1.16667,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.33333,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.6,1.6,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.66667,1.73333,1.73333,1.73333,1.73333,1.73333,1.73333,1.8,1.8,1.8,1.8,1.8,1.86667,1.86667,1.86667,1.92857,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,1.93333,2.,2.06667,2.07143,2.07143,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.13333,2.14286,2.14286,2.14286,2.19048,2.25,2.25,2.25,2.25,2.25,2.27778,2.28571,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.32143,2.33333,2.35714,2.4,2.5,2.51515,2.57778,2.57778,2.62121,2.64444,2.64444,2.64444,2.66667,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.68889,2.69091,2.71795,2.84848,2.87879,2.89394,2.98095,3.01515,3.01515,3.02857,3.06061,3.06061,3.15385,3.16484,3.16484,3.19697,3.24242,3.26374,3.27473,3.27473,3.44167,3.45833,3.48366,3.5,3.6,3.66667,3.97044,4.00833,4.07792,4.14667,4.22105,4.61846,6.35829,18.603,18.9127,20.0815,21.4653,21.8075,23.1257,23.174,23.195,24.8591,25.5128,25.6204,25.7491,27.2341,28.6521,29.1464,29.2351,29.9114,30.1133,30.7835,31.6615,32.4578,32.6746,34.5677,34.9822,35.3298,35.3304,35.5266,36.5512,36.9395,38.5341,38.5421,39.0514,44.5931,47.1162,63.3183,64.7268,72.3538,80.9747,87.87,90.8965}

    FindDistribution[data1, 3, {"CramerVonMises", "PearsonChiSquare"}, 
     "RandomSeed" -> 23544325]
{{MixtureDistribution[{0.950331, 
    0.0496689}, {LogNormalDistribution[0.354894, 0.349561], 
    LogNormalDistribution[3.62601, 0.392707]}], {0.0000939677, 
   1.61301*10^-90}}, {MixtureDistribution[{0.9503, 
    0.0496998}, {LogNormalDistribution[0.354858, 0.349509], 
    GammaDistribution[5.66106, 7.257]}], {0.0000935481, 
   1.61301*10^-90}}, {MixtureDistribution[{0.936836, 
    0.0631641}, {NormalDistribution[1.48875, 0.529605], 
    NormalDistribution[33.145, 23.7551]}], {0.0000256599, 
   1.04431*10^-135}}}
```

How can I make  `FindDistribution` perform better  in this case?

NB: This is an experimental data and it is what it is.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using? On Windows 7 *Mathematica* 10.4.1 and 11.1.1 the `GammaDistribution`, `LogNormalDistribution`, and `Weibull` are not the top 3 models.

Comment: I wonder if the discrepancy has to do with the large number of ties in your data?  The following produces identical P-values:  `data = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[7.34584, 0.0353382], 122]
dataDist = FindDistribution[data, 1, {"PearsonChiSquare"}]
DistributionFitTest[data, dataDist[[1, 1]], {"PearsonChiSquare"}]`

Comment: If you add a small amount of noise to get rid of the ties, the differences in the P-values go away:  `data = data + 
  RandomVariate[UniformDistribution[{-0.00001, 0.00001}], 
   Length[data]]`.  (This is not a recommended fix.  If you have lots of ties, then you don't have appropriate data for these tests.  One can do other tests but those you should ask about on CrossValidated.)

Comment: @Jim Baldwin. I use Mathematica 11.Not sure why we don't get the same top 3 models. Did you use ""RandomSeed"->23544325 ? I understood what you said and I will post  a question in CrossValidated but still I am not able to wrap my head around it. If ties are the main issue then the Cramer and Pearson tests should have failed anyway regardless of the function used.Am I completely wrong ? also I actually  tried all the other tests available under the DistributionFitTest including KS and they failed as well. Intriguingly  the KS works just fine with the same data set using R!

Comment: @Jim Baldwin. I asked another friend to run the same data and he obtained the same top 3 models.

Comment: I did use that same random seed on both a Windows 7 and Windows 10 PC and did not get your results.  However, it's not `FindDistribution` that's the problem.  Your expectations about finding a continuous distribution with so many ties when `FindDistribution` does not assume ties are a possibility is the problem.  Your other dataset is even worse in that respect.  A histogram of the values (and the log of those values) demonstrates that a nice smooth curve form with few parameters is just not achievable.  R might not have failed for the test but the fit is still poor.