# Why does the PearsonChiSquare from FindDistribution and DistributionFitTest differ by a factor of $10^{20}$?

Tags: fitting, distributions

This is similar to the unanswered "[Why the results of FindDistribution and DistributionFitTest are not consistent?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/149555/why-the-results-of-finddistribution-and-distributionfittest-are-not-consistent)" My more specific question is: Why do the PearsonChiSquare values for `FindDistribution` and `DistributionFitTest` differ by a factor of over $10^{20}$? And is either correct?

```
data = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/heaneym/data"];
FindDistribution[data, 1, "PearsonChiSquare"]
```

> {{FrechetDistribution[9.84969, 1.73896, -1.53907], 0.113153}}

```
edist1 = %[[1, 1]];
DistributionFitTest[data, edist1, "PearsonChiSquare"]
```

> 6.60413*10^-22

```
hist = Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF", PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True];
fit = Plot[PDF[edist1, x], {x, -1, 3}, PlotRange -> All];
Show[hist, fit]
```

[image]

Comment: I edited the question to remove a misinterpretation you may have made: please try it again.

Comment: I think you need to include the output.  As @kglr states the values for `DistributionFitTest[data, edist1, "PearsonChiSquare"]` and `PearsonChiSquareTest[data, edist1]` are identical but differ from `FindDistribution[data, 1, "PearsonChiSquare"]`.  (Note that each time one runs the code, one gets a different answer although the ratios of the *P*-values are about the same because of an internal random factor).  The difference is  because you're testing two different hypotheses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an extended comment because the documentation for `FindDistribution` is simply inadequate.

Consider the following statements and the resulting output:

```
SeedRandom[12345];

FindDistribution[data, 1, "PearsonChiSquare"]
(* {{FrechetDistribution[5.2812, 0.876497, -0.698011], 0.344152}} *)

FindDistribution[data, 1, "PearsonChiSquare", TargetFunctions -> {FrechetDistribution}]
(* {{FrechetDistribution[4.0228, 0.593035, -0.404229], 2.86527*10^-14}} *)

edist1 = %[[1, 1]];
DistributionFitTest[data, edist1, "PearsonChiSquare"]
(* 2.86527*10^-14 *)
```

So when one has a single target function, the results match perfectly between `FindDistribution` and `DistributionFitTest`.

*Mathematica* is doing some undocumented funny business with random choices when  multiple target distributions are considered.  It is probably some Bayesian process (which is not necessarily a bad thing).  The problem is the lack of documentation and that the funny business occurs as the default.

Comment: So then how can we use MMA to find the best fitting distribution of data, if it is ranking the quality of fit  by wildly inaccurate values of PearsonChiSquare?

Comment: "It depends."  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/288867/how-to-determine-the-best-distribution-to-fit-my-data for a good answer.  What I would add to that is even more emphasis on the objective.  How good a fit do you need?  And how would you characterize the measure of fit?  A *P*-value can't tell you that.  That's a subject matter decision.  If *P*-values were all one needed, why would we statisticians need subject matter experts?  And even small departures will get you small *P*-values with large enough sample sizes.

Comment: That is an enlightening link.

Comment: What is the purpose of SeedRandom[12345];?

Comment: Because some *Mathematica* functions (such as `FindDistribution` and `RandomVariate`) produce random numbers, using `SeedRandom[ - some number -]` makes sure that any user can exactly duplicate the same "random" results on their computer.  And it's handy when you're trying to debug code that has random numbers, i.e, the code will operate on the same randomly generated dataset.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Wolfram tech support about this issue, here is their response:
"I have the confirmation from our developers that there is in fact an issue with the functionality that needs to be fixed. I have filed a report of this issue using the information that you  provided, and have included your contact information in my report."

Comment: Very good.  Hope it gets fixed soon.